# Mapping a single element to a record using Scripting Functoid

Tags: xslt, scripting, mapping, biztalk

I am trying to create a mapping between two different elements(Element1 & Element2) from source schema to the same  record on Destination Schema along with an element in it as shown in the following format.

```
<coverages>
  //If Element1(Source Schema element) has data
  <coverage>
    <CoverageTypeCd>Data1</CoverageTypeCd>
  </coverage>    

  //If Element2(Source Schema element) has data
  <coverage>
    <CoverageTypeCd>Data2</CoverageTypeCd>
  </coverage>
</coverages>
```

I am now trying to check the presence of value on Elements(Source Schema) and then trying to feed it to the scripting functoid. I don’t know how I should produce the entire
`<coverage>` node and still send the respective `<coverageTypeCd>` of that record as shown above. I believe it should be done with Inline XSLT. I really need someone’s help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Please let me know if you need additional details on something.

**Update**

Hi folks, I found the answer myself. I used `Inline XSLT Call template` as Script Type and it did the job. I applied this script for different elements on Source Schema to map the Coverage record

```
<xsl:template name="CoverageTemplate1"> 
  <xsl:param name="Element1" /> 
  <xsl:element name="Coverage"> 
    <xsl:element name="CoverageTypeCd">
      <xsl:value-of select="$Element1" />
    </xsl:element> 
  </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi folks, I found the answer myself. I used "Inline XSLT Call template" as Script Type and it did the job. I applied this script for different elements on Source Schema to map the Coverage record     

<xsl:template name="CoverageTemplate1"> 
<xsl:param name="Element1" />
<xsl:element name="Coverage">
<xsl:element name="CoverageTypeCd"><xsl:value-of select="$Element1" /></xsl:element> </xsl:element> </xsl:template> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. I used "Inline XSLT Call template" as Script Type and it did the job. I applied this script for different elements on Source Schema to map the Coverage record

```
<xsl:template name="CoverageTemplate1"> 
<xsl:param name="Element1" /> 
<xsl:element name="Coverage">
 <xsl:element name="CoverageTypeCd"><xsl:value-of    
select="$Element1" /></xsl:element>     
</xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks